# Vaadin grid setBodyRowHeight doesn't exist in latest 8.1.4 API

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm trying to adjust the height of the rows since I'm using components and the [Vaadin Grid documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html) says you can do this by calling `setBodyRowHeight` however that method no longer seems to be available...

UPDATE: I found the method `setRowHeight()` (the manual needs updating) however this also changes the column header row height which I don't want, I just want the rows to be taller (so the component fits) and not the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is an issue in the latest version and as a result it's not possible to do what the user manual states. That being said it is expected to be resolved in version 8.2.0: https://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/8.2/8.2.0/8.2.0.alpha1/release-notes.html